# Cakephp Ajax search with Pagination from POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to create a search option in my cakephp 2.x project.

Here is my controller code-

```
    public function admin_index() {
    $this->Customer->recursive = 0;
    $this->Paginator->settings = array('order' => 'Customer.id DESC');
    $this->set('customers', $this->Paginator->paginate());

    // search form data
    $clients = $this->Customer->Client->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('clients'));     
}

public function admin_search() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    if ( $this->request->is(array('post', 'ajax')) ) {
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($this->request->data['Customer'] as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value))
            $conditions[$key . ' LIKE'] = '%' . $value . '%';
        }

        $this->Customer->recursive = 0;
        $this->Paginator->settings = array('order' => 'Customer.id DESC', 'conditions' => $conditions);
        $this->set('customers', $this->Paginator->paginate());          
    }
}
```

And here is my view code-

index.ctp

```
            <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Customer', array(
            'action'    => 'search',
            'class'     => 'form-inline',
            //'novalidate' => true,
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'label' => false,
                'div'   => 'form-group',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => false,
            )
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('client_id', array(
            'empty'         => '--Select Client--'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('uid', array(
            'placeholder'   => 'UID'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('device', array(
            'placeholder'   => 'Device'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('debug', array(
            'placeholder'   => 'Debug',
            'options'       => array(1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'),
            'empty'         => '--Please Select--'
        ));         
        echo $this->Form->end();        
        ?>

<div id="result">   </div>
```

```
$("form").on('change keyup',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        url     : "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'search', 'admin')); ?>",
        success : function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false; //stop the actual form post !important!
}) ;
```

search.ctp

```
<?php if(!empty($customers)): ?>            
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('client_id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('uid'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('device'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('created'); ?></th>
        <th class="text-center"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('debug'); ?></th>
        <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$index = 0;
$paginatorParams = $this->Paginator->params();
?>      
<?php foreach ($customers as $customer): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php $index++; echo $index + ( ((int)$this->Paginator->counter('{:page}') - 1) * $paginatorParams['limit'] ); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($customer['Client']['name'], array('controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'view', $customer['Client']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo h($customer['Customer']['uid']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($customer['Customer']['device']) . ' ' . h($customer['Customer']['version']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($customer['Customer']['created']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-sm <?php echo h($customer['Customer']['debug']) ? 'label-danger' : 'label-success' ?>"><?php echo $debug[h($customer['Customer']['debug'])]; ?></span></td>
    <td class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $customer['Customer']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $customer['Customer']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-warning')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $customer['Customer']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger'), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $customer['Customer']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $this->element('paginate'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
Customer not found
<?php endif; ?>
```

This perfectly returning the result.
But the problem is when I want to go to the next page of the search result it returns error. Because this time I'm not sending the parameters to controller. I don't know how to do that.

Can you please, help me out?

Comment: I think you should have combined your ajax pagination + search using the https://github.com/CakeDC/search plugin. This way you would a) have proper fallbacks using PRG pattern b) provide those fallback URLs with the posted data as querystrings also in your ajax returned URLs. This way you dont lose any of your input on (AJAX or not) page change. And of course you need to understand the difference between GET and POST here. The former is for changing pages then, the latter for filtering and posting data only.

Comment: Thanks @mark. What is the cakephp way? If I want to do this in get method. Then how can I get these parameters in next page call?

Comment: By using what I just told you: The search plugin to make proper PRG redirects (faked with ajax of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function admin_index() {

        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Admins Manager');
        $countries = $this->Country->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'country_name'), 'order' => array('country_name' => 'asc')));
        $this->set(compact('countries'));
        $this->set('total_users', $this->User->find('count', array('condition' => array('User.role_id' => 2))));
    }

    public function admin_list() {
        $this->layout = false;

        if (isset($this->request->data['customActionType']) && $this->request->data['customActionType'] == 'group_action') {
            $this->User->updateAll(array('User.status' => $this->request->data['customActionName']), array('User.id' => $this->request->data['id']));
        }

        $phone_con = $shop_name_con = $con = $email_con = $name_con = $country_con = $status_con = array();

        if (isset($this->request->data['name']) && $this->request->data['name'] != '') {
            $name_con = array('User.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data['name'] . '%');
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['email']) && $this->request->data['email'] != '') {
            $email_con = array('User.email LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data['email'] . '%');
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['shop_name']) && $this->request->data['shop_name'] != '') {
            $shop_name_con = array('User.shop_name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->data['shop_name'] . '%');
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['phone']) && $this->request->data['phone'] != '') {
            $phone_con = array('User.phone' => $this->request->data['phone']);
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['country_id']) && $this->request->data['country_id'] != '') {
            $country_con = array('User.country_id' => $this->request->data['country_id']);
        }

        if (isset($this->request->data['status']) && $this->request->data['status'] != '') {
            $status_con = array('User.status' => $this->request->data['status']);
        }

        switch ($this->request->data['order'][0]['column']) {
            case 1:
                $order = array('User.name' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            case 2:
                $order = array('User.email' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            case 3:
                $order = array('User.shop_name' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            case 4:
                $order = array('Country.country_name' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            case 5:
                $order = array('User.phone' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            case 7:
                $order = array('User.status' => $this->request->data['order'][0]['dir']);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (isset($this->request->data['start']) && $this->request->data['start'] != $this->request->data['length']) {
            $page = ($this->request->data['start'] / $this->request->data['length']) + 1;
        } elseif ($this->request->data['start'] == $this->request->data['length']) {
            $page = 2;
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $con = array_merge($phone_con, $shop_name_con, $email_con, $name_con, $country_con, $status_con, array('User.role_id' => 2));
        $this->paginate = array('conditions' => $con, 'limit' => $this->request->data['length'], 'order' => $order, 'page' => $page);
        $this->User->recursive = 1;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));
        //pr($this->paginate('User'));die;
    }
```

view file

```
 <script src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>js/admin.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            Metronic.init(); // init metronic core componets
            Layout.init(); // init layout
            TableAjax.init();               
        });
    </script>        
    <?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>
```

admin_index file

```
    <script>
        var total_users =<?php echo $total_users; ?>;
        var total_data =<?php echo $total_users; ?>;
        var aTargets = [0, 7];
        var tOrder = [1, "asc"];
        var ajaxUrl = path + prefix + "/users/list";

    </script>
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
            <h3 class="page-title">
                <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
            </h3>
            <?php echo $this->Common->sessionFlash(); ?>
            <div class="page-bar">
                <ul class="page-breadcrumb">                            
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Admins</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <!-- Begin: life time stats -->
                    <div class="portlet">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="fa fa-users"></i>Admins Listing
                            </div>
                            <div class="actions">

                                <a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add')); ?>" class="btn green yellow-stripe">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    <span class="hidden-480">
                                        New Admin </span>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body">
                            <div class="table-container">
                                <div class="table-actions-wrapper">
                                    <span>
                                    </span>
                                    <select class="table-group-action-input form-control input-inline input-small input-sm">
                                        <option value="">Select...</option>
                                        <option value="1">Enabled</option>
                                        <option value="0">Disabled</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm yellow table-group-action-submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span class="hidden-480">Submit</span> </button>
                                </div>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable_ajax">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr role="row" class="heading">
                                            <th width="2%">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable">
                                            </th>
                                            <th width="15%">
                                                Name
                                            </th>                                       
                                            <th width="12%">
                                                Email
                                            </th>
                                            <th width="15%">
                                                Shop Name
                                            </th>                                                                             
                                            <th width="10%">
                                                Country
                                            </th>                                                                             
                                            <th width="10%">
                                                Phone
                                            </th>                                                                      
                                            <th width="10%">
                                                Status
                                            </th>
                                            <th width="18%">
                                                Actions
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr role="row" class="filter">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm')); ?>  
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm')); ?>   
                                            </td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $this->Form->input('shop_name', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm')); ?>   </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('country_id', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm', 'empty' => 'Select')); ?>   
                                            </td>
                                            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('label' => false, 'div' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm')); ?> </td>                                      

                                            <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('status', array('options' => array(1 => 'Enabled', 0 => 'Disabled'), 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm', 'empty' => 'Select')); ?></td>                                       
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="pull-left margin-bottom-5">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-sm yellow filter-submit margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> <span class="hidden-480">Search</span></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <button class="btn btn-sm red filter-cancel"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> <span class="hidden-480">Reset</span></button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End: life time stats -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="basic" id="ajax-version-view" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="page-loading page-loading-boxed">
            <img class="loading" alt="" src="<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif">
            <span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Loading... </span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

admin_list

    <?php

    //pr($rooms);die;
    /*
     * Paging
     */

    $iTotalRecords = $this->params['paging']['User']['count'];
    //  $iDisplayLength = intval($_REQUEST['length']);
    //  $iDisplayLength = $iDisplayLength < 0 ? $iTotalRecords : $iDisplayLength; 
    //  $iDisplayStart = intval($_REQUEST['start']);
    $sEcho = intval($_REQUEST['draw']);

    $records = array();
    $records["data"] = array();

    //  $end = $iDisplayStart + $iDisplayLength;
    //  $end = $end > $iTotalRecords ? $iTotalRecords : $end; '<a href="'.Router::url(array('admin'=>true,'controller' => 'rooms', 'action' => 'view')).'" class="btn btn-xs blue"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View</a>'.
    //pr($users);
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $id = $user['User']['id'];
        $status = $user['User']['status'];
        $label = ($status == 1) ? 'success' : 'danger';
        $label_text = ($status == 1) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
        $delete = $this->BootForm->postLink('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> <span class="hidden-480">Delete</span>', array('action' => 'delete', $id), array('confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete %s?', $user['User']['name']), 'class' => 'btn default btn-xs red', 'escape' => false));
        $records["data"][] = array(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' . $id . '">',
            $user['User']['name'],
            $user['User']['email'],
            $user['User']['shop_name'],        
            $user['Country']['country_name'],
            $user['User']['phone'],
            '<span class="label label-sm label-' . ($label) . '">' . $label_text . '</span>',
            '<a class="btn default btn-xs purple" href="' . Router::url(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit', $id)) . '"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span class="hidden-480">Edit</span> </a>' . $delete,
        );
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST["customActionType"]) && $_REQUEST["customActionType"] == "group_action") {
        $records["customActionStatus"] = "OK"; // pass custom message(useful for getting status of group actions)
        $records["customActionMessage"] = "Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!"; // pass custom message(useful for getting status of group actions)
    }

    $records["draw"] = $sEcho;
    $records["recordsTotal"] = $iTotalRecords;
    $records["recordsFiltered"] = $iTotalRecords;

    echo json_encode($records);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("pattern", function (value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (typeof param === 'string') {
        param = new RegExp('^(?:' + param + ')$');
    }
    return param.test(value);
}, "Invalid format.");
/*
 * Account Setting Class
 */
var AccountSetting = function () {
    var resetFormValidate = function () {
        $('.user_reset_password').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            rules: {
                'data[User][password]': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6

                },
                'data[User][confirm_password]': {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#UserPassword"

                }
            }, messages: {
                'data[User][password]': {
                    required: 'Please enter new password.',
                    minlength: 'New password must be at least 6 characters long'
                },
                'data[User][confirm_password]': {
                    required: 'Please enter confirm password.',
                    equalTo: "New password and confirm password not match."
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
            }
        });
    }
    var changeFormValidate = function () {
        $('.user_change_password_form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[User][password]': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                'data[User][confirm_password]': {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#UserPassword"

                },
                'data[User][old_password]': {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {url: SITE_URL + 'ajax/check_password', type: 'POST', data: {field: 'old_password'}}

                }
            }, messages: {
                'data[User][password]': {
                    required: 'Please enter new password.',
                    minlength: 'Password must be at least 6 characters long.'
                },
                'data[User][confirm_password]': {
                    required: 'Please enter confirm password.',
                    equalTo: "Password and confirm password not match."
                },
                'data[User][old_password]': {
                    required: 'Please enter current password.',
                    remote: 'Current password is wrong.'
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });
    }
    var editFormValidate = function () {
        $('.user_edit_profile_form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[User][first_name]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][last_name]': {
                    required: true
                },
            }, messages: {
                'data[User][first_name]': {
                    required: 'Please enter first name.'
                },
                'data[User][last_name]': {
                    required: 'Please enter last name.'
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            editFormValidate();
            resetFormValidate();
            changeFormValidate();
        }
    };
}();
/*
 * User Class
 */
var Users = function () {
    var userFormValidate = function () {
        $('.user-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[User][first_name]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][last_name]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][email]': {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {url: SITE_URL + 'ajax/check_field', type: 'POST', data: {field: 'email'}}
                },
                'data[User][shop_name]': {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {url: SITE_URL + 'ajax/check_field', type: 'POST', data: {field: 'shop_name'}}
                },
                'data[User][shop_description]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][specialty]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][country_id]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][phone]': {
                    required: true,
                    pattern: /^[\d\s]+$/,
                    maxlength: 15,
                },
                'data[User][address]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[User][image]': {
                    extension: "jpg|jpeg|png"
                },
            }, messages: {
                'data[User][first_name]': {
                    required: 'Please enter first name.'
                },
                'data[User][last_name]': {
                    required: 'Please enter last name.'
                },
                'data[User][email]': {
                    required: 'Please enter email address.',
                    remote: 'Email address already exist.'
                },
                'data[User][shop_name]': {
                    required: 'Please enter shop name.',
                    remote: 'Shop name already exist.'
                },
                'data[User][shop_description]': {
                    required: 'Please enter shop description.'
                },
                'data[User][specialty]': {
                    required: 'Please enter specialty.'
                },
                'data[User][country_id]': {
                    required: 'Please select country.'
                },
                'data[User][phone]': {
                    required: 'Please enter phone.',
                    pattern: 'Please enter valid phone.',
                    maxlength: 'Phone is no more than 15 digits.'
                },
                'data[User][address]': {
                    required: 'Please enter address.'
                },
                'data[User][image]': {
                    extension: 'Please select jpg, jpeg, png image.'
                },
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.is('input[type="file"]')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('.body-img'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            userFormValidate();
        }
    };
}();
/*
 * Schedule  Class
 */
var Schedule = function () {
    var oTable;
    var table;
    var nEditing = null;
    var nNew = false;
    var setTimePicker = function () {
        $('.timepicker-no-seconds').timepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            minuteStep: 1
        });
    }
    var scheduleFormValidate = function () {
        $('.schedule-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[Schedule][start_time]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[Schedule][end_time]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[Schedule][days][]': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1
                }
            }, messages: {
                'data[Schedule][start_time]': {
                    required: 'Please enter start time.'
                },
                'data[Schedule][end_time]': {
                    required: 'Please enter end time.'
                },
                'data[Schedule][days][]': {
                    required: 'Please select days.'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parents('.days-body').is('div')) {
                    error.attr('id', 'days-error')
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('.days-body'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });

    }
    var setSlotActive = function () {
        if ($('.slot-time-body input:checked').is('input')) {
            $('.slot-time-body input:checked').parent('label').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.slot-time-body input:first').click();
        }
    }
    var setStatus = function () {
        $('body').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', '#working', function (event, state) {
            var userId = $(this).data('user');
            var scheduleId = $(this).data('schedule');
            var weekId = $(this).data('week');
            var data = {'user_id': userId, 'schedule_id': scheduleId, 'week_id': weekId, 'status': state};
            $.ajax({
                url: SITE_URL + 'ajax/set_working',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    Metronic.blockUI({
                        message: 'Please wait..',
                        target: $('.table-container'),
                        overlayColor: 'grey',
                        cenrerY: true,
                        boxed: true
                    });
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    Metronic.unblockUI($('.table-container'));

                }
            })
        })
    }
    var reSchedule = function () {
        table = $('.table-schedule');
        oTable = table.dataTable({
            bSort: false,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bPaginate: false,
            bLengthChange: false
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.reschedule-btn', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /* Get the row as a parent of the link that was clicked on */
            var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

            if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
                /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
                restoreRow(nEditing);
                editRow(nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            } else {
                /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
                editRow(nRow);
                nEditing = nRow;
            }
        })
    }
    var cancelReSchedule = function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.cancel-schedule', function () {
            restoreRow(nEditing);
            nEditing = null;
        })
    }
    var saveSchedule = function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.save-schedule', function () {
            if ($('input[name="data[Schedule][start_time]"]').val() == '' || $('input[name="data[Schedule][end_time]"]').val() == '') {
                Metronic.alert({
                    type: 'danger',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    message: 'Please select valid time.',
                    container: $('#form_wizard_1'),
                    place: 'prepend'
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: SITE_URL + 'ajax/change_schedule',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('input,select', nEditing).serializeArray(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        Metronic.blockUI({
                            message: 'Please wait..',
                            target: $('.table-container'),
                            overlayColor: 'grey',
                            cenrerY: true,
                            boxed: true
                        });
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var res = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (res.error == 1) {
                            Metronic.unblockUI($('.table-container'));
                            Metronic.alert({
                                type: 'danger',
                                icon: 'warning',
                                message: res.msg,
                                container: $('#form_wizard_1'),
                                place: 'prepend'
                            });
                        } else {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
    var editRow = function (nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
        if ($(nRow).find('input[name="data[working]"]').is('input')) {
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="data[Schedule][start_time]" class="form-control timepicker-no-seconds" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="data[Schedule][end_time]" class="form-control timepicker-no-seconds" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<select  name="data[Schedule][slot_time]" class="form-control"><option  value="30">30 Minute</option><option value="45">45 Minute</option><option value="60">1 Hour</option></select>';
            $('select[name="data[Schedule][slot_time]"] option[value="' + parseInt(aData[3]) + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
        } else {
            jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="data[Schedule][start_time]" class="form-control timepicker-no-seconds" value="">';
            jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="data[Schedule][end_time]" class="form-control timepicker-no-seconds" value="">';
            jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<select name="data[Schedule][slot_time]" class="form-control"><option value="30">30 Minute</option><option value="45">45 Minute</option><option value="60">1 Hour</option></select>';
            jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<select name="data[Schedule][working]" class="form-control"><option value="1">Yes</option><option value="0">No</option></select>';
        }
        jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<button class="btn  btn-sm blue save-schedule"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button><button class="btn  btn-sm red cancel-schedule"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel </button>';
        setTimePicker();
    }
    var restoreRow = function (nRow) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

        for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
        }

        oTable.fnDraw();
    }
    var checkBreak = function () {
        $('body').on('change', 'input[name="data[LunchBreak][slot_id][]"]', function () {
            if ($('input[name="data[LunchBreak][slot_id][]"]:checked').length) {
                $('.lunch-submit').removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('.lunch-submit').addClass('disabled');
            }

        })
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            setTimePicker();
            scheduleFormValidate();
            setSlotActive();
            setStatus();
            reSchedule();
            cancelReSchedule();
            saveSchedule();
            checkBreak();
        }
    };
}();
/*
 * Setting  Class
 */
var Setting = function () {
    var settingFormValidate = function () {
        $('.setting-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[Setting][0][value]': {
                    required: true
                },
                'data[Setting][1][value]': {
                    required: true,
                    number: true,
                    min: 1,
                    pattern: '^[0-9]+$'
                }
            }, messages: {
                'data[Setting][0][value]': {
                    required: 'Please enter site title.'
                },
                'data[Setting][1][value]': {
                    required: 'Please enter schedule Hour.',
                    pattern: 'Please enter valid schedule Hour.'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            settingFormValidate();
        }
    };
}();
/*
 * Barber  Class
 */
var Barber = function () {
    var addVacationFormValidate = function () {
        $('.vacation-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input 
            rules: {
                'data[Vacation][date][]': {
                    required: true
                }
            }, messages: {
                'data[Vacation][date][]': {
                    required: 'Please enter date.'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                label.remove();
            },
        });
    }
    var addMoreDate = function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.add-more-date', function () {
            var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group');
            var clone = parent.clone();
            $('input', clone).val('');
            $('.help-block', clone).remove();
            $(clone).removeClass('has-error');
            $('.btn-body a.add-more-date', parent).remove();
            $('.btn-body', parent).html('<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger remove-more-date">Remove</a>');
            clone.insertAfter(parent);
            setDatePicker();
        })
    }
    var removeMoreDate = function () {
        $('body').on('click', '.remove-more-date', function () {
            $(this).parents('.form-group').remove();
        });
    }
    var setDatePicker = function () {
        $('.vacation-date').datepicker({
            "startDate": new Date(),
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
        });
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            addVacationFormValidate();
            setDatePicker();
            addMoreDate();
            removeMoreDate();
        }
    };
}();
```